# Multiple UI subscribing to data from a single thread + progress report

Tags: c#, winforms, task, progress

I have a UI Form ("Main") that launches a worker thread ("Engine") which fetches data from a feed.
The same UI form has the ability to launch new identical UI forms ("Workspaces") with different parameters passed, which subscribe to different data updates based on their parameters from Engine like so:

```
public partial class Workspace : Form
    Engine e;

    public Workspace(Engine e, List<Specifications> params)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        engine = e;
        StartTracking();
    }

    private async void StartTracking()
    {
        var progress = new Progress<Dictionary<string, Data>>(a => UpdateData(a));
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => engine.StartTracking(progress), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }

    public void UpdateData(Dictionary<string, Data> data)
    {
        statusGrid.DataSource = data.Values.ToList();
    }
```

My reason for doing this is that there is a large overlap between which data each Workspace subscribes to, and I would rather not fetch the same data x number of times.

The issue now, is that if I start a number of new Workspaces, only the most recent one will receive updates and the others will stop subscribing. I am creating Workspaces in Main as follows:

```
public partial class Main : Form

    var thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        Workspace f = new Workspace(engine, params);
        Application.Run(f);
    });
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();

public class Engine : IDisposable

    public IProgress<Dictionary<string, Data>> progress;

    public void StartTracking(IProgress<Dictionary<string, Data>> p)
    {
        progress = p;
    }
```

Is this correct?

Also,

- Is there a way to redirect a progress update to the correct thread? I am currently calling it as such:

  progress.Report(m_data);
- Is Progress the preferred method to use, or should I go back to using Invoke/BeginInvoke to update the UI threads?

Comment: What's in `StartTracking()`? My first guess is that you've got one instance of `engine`, which has one instance of `Progress<Dictionary<string, Data>>`, and you're replacing it each time you start a new one. Or something like that. Whatever you're using for the engine to talk to the workspaces, what you're describing suggests that you've only got one of it.

Comment: You are correct! That's exactly what's happening! Should I be adding these progress objects to a List<T> ? How do I track the progress across all my UI's? Also, given that the Dictionary<string, Data> contains the data  ALL workspaces need, I will need to filter it once it is returned to the respective UI.

Comment: Well, then. Maybe your engine needs a `List<Progress<Dictionary<string, Data>>>`. But the simplest way to "multicast" the same thing to multiple listeners is an `event` -- a.k.a. a multicast delegate. A single event can have any number of subscribers. Raise it once, and they all get it.

Comment: Engine does create and maintain the only copy of the full data. I don't quite understand though - how do I give Engine the same UpdateData delegate?

Comment: Oops, I misread the `StartTracking` snippet. Does that just get called once, on startup? I thought each workspace was passing in a Progress and an UpdateData delegate. My bad. I need to see the actual code where you add workspaces. You said "That's exactly what's happening!" -- Can I see the code where "that" happens?

Comment: StartTracking is called once, on startup of each Workspace. You are correct where I am essentially overwriting the process object in Engine:  `public IProgress<Dictionary<string, Data>> progress;   public void StartTracking(IProgress<Dictionary<string, Data>> p)
        {
            progress = p;
        }`

Comment: "once, on startup of each Workspace" *isn't* once. It's again and again and again.

Comment: Look, this guessing game is impossible. I need to see enough code to understand what's actually happening. You're showing me code and I don't even know what class it's in or who's calling it, or when.

Comment: Correct - I will change this so that the Progress object is created before the Workspace, and then passed in to each Workspace. How do I ensure that it runs UpdateDate on each individual Workspace? I am not quite sure how to pass in a delegate? Also - should I be using Progress, or is the traditional delegate Invoke/BeginInvoke the way to go here? Thank you so much for your help Ed!

Comment: So you could give Engine a private `List<Progress<...>> _progresses` and just add to it for each new workspace. Then instead of `progress.Report(m_data)`, you would do `foreach (var p in _progresses) { p.Report(m_data); }`. That might be simplest.

Comment: When workspaces unsubscribe (if they ever do), you'd want to remove them from that list. Maybe instead of a list it should be `Dictionary<Workspace, Progress<...>` -- then you'd loop through `_progresses.Values` to call `p.Report` on each one, and when a Workspace unsubscribes, it would pass in its own `this` to the `Engine.StopTracking(Workspace ws)` method and StopTracking would call `_progresses.Remove(ws);`.

Comment: Ideally the solution that creates the least overhead - Engine should do the least amount of processing required other than fetching data feed updates. I will go with the `Dictionary<Workspace, Progress<...>>` solution as this seems most straightforward to implement.

Comment: Simplicity of implementation is the gold standard. I'd worry about overhead if/when it becomes an issue. Let me know if that gets it working right and I'll put it in as an answer.

Comment: For reporting back to UI use in your progress handling Dispatcher.

Comment: @PawelTroka What is the advantage/disadvantage of using dispatcher and Invoke/BeginInvoke vs using the .net 4.5 Progress object?